# Playlist loading issues after upgrading to Xcode 4.5 and iOS Simulator 6

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Having issues with the callback from spotify when I'm trying to load my playlists in my iOS app. It worked out well before the upgrade. When I'm receiving the callback it's only a handful of the playlists that is getting loaded, some of them doesn't get loaded at all.

Someone that knows if it is a known issue?

EDIT: Working now!

Comment: If the solution is working the best thing you can do is to accept the answer and vote it up if you can leave a comment stating it. Writing `WORKING NOW` causes ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, an upgrade like this is unlikely to affect CocoaLibSpotify in this way since most of the logic is in libSpotify, a pre-built package that won't change at all when you rebuild with a new SDK (it's a static library).

However, this *will* happen from time to time when the Spotify playlist service is slow, down, or suffering with some ailment or other. You should make sure your application behaves itself in this situation.